# Sense of secure cookie over HTTPS

Tags: cookies, ssl, https

Is there any sense to encrypt cookies (secure cookies) for HTTPS?
As far as I know in HTTPS whole request is encrypted, so do we need additional encryption of cookies?

Comment: Hey look, this cookie has my username in it. I'm going to change my username to the username of a known admin and see what happens.

Comment: Ah. Good response. Thanks.

Comment: Just to point out that "secure cookie" usually refers to a cookie with the secure flag. Nothing to do with encryption/signing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends entirely on your security model.  Some reasons why you would still need to encrypt cookies:

1. Do you care if the user of your application gets the contents of the cookie?  In other words, do you store anything there that's internal and shouldn't be disclosed to the user?
2. Do you care if the user tampers with the contents of the cookie?  Encryption can be a way to get integrity protection depending on how you do it.  (There are, of course, other ways as well.)
3. What are the consequences of disclosure of the cookie?  If it's a bearer token, whether it's encrypted or not won't make a lot of difference, but if it contains valuable data, encrypting it provides some protection against an attacker gaining access to the browser's stored cookies in some way (whether via a web attack or an attack on the actual system hosting the browser).  You still may lose to an attacker in other ways, but it could provide some defense in depth.

The main thing that encrypting the cookie gives you is protection against the user who receives the cookie (or an attacker who can access that user's data), if you need that.